# Probability in Distribution Function

Tags: probability

If $X$ has the distribution function

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 1 \\
      \frac{1}{3} & 1\leq x < 4 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & 4\leq x < 6 \\
      \frac{5}{6} & 6 \leq x < 10\\
      1 & x \geq 10 
   \end{cases}$

find $P(2 < X \leq 6)$ and $P(X=4)$.

$P(2 < X \leq 6) = P(X \leq 6) - P(X\leq 2) = \frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$.

$P(X = 4) = P(X\leq 4) - P(X< 4) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$.

---

Similarly,

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < -1 \\
      \frac{1}{4} & -1\leq x < 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & 4\leq x < 3 \\
      \frac{3}{4} & 3 \leq x < 5\\
      1 & x \geq 5 
   \end{cases}$

Find $P(X \leq 3), \;P(X= 3), \; P(X < 3), \; P(X \geq 1), \; P(-0.4 < X < 4), \; P(X = 5)$.

$P(X \leq 3)=  \frac{3}{4}$

$P(X = 3) = P(X \leq 3) - P(X< 3) = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(X < 3) = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X < 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{4}$

$P(-0.4 < X < 4) = P(X <4) - P(X \leq -0.4) = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2} $

$P(X = 5) = P(X \leq 5) - P(X < 5) = 1 - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$

---

Does anyone mind checking my work? I am still trying to understand the Distribution function

Comment: In the first case, you probably mean $F(x) = 1/3,\quad 1\le x <4$, right?

Comment: @thanasissdr Yes! Sorry for the typo.

Comment: It looks ok to me (just a small correction: in the second case you probably mean $F(x) = 1/2, \quad 1\le x<3).$

Comment: Gosh darnit. Typos everywhere. Thank you for the feedback. The one's I felt confused about where the strictly less-than inequalities such as $P(X < 3)$.

Comment: You may take a look at [this](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/CDF.html). Personally, I would write one more step, i.e. $P(X\le a) = F(a)$ and $P(X<a)  =F(a^-)$.